# Getting an error issuing a post request in c#

Tags: c#, .net, http, post, asynchronous

I want to issue a post request in a c# app to https://www.inventor-s-hub.xyz:8000/v8
but I keep getting this error --> System.Net.WebException: the remote name couldn't be resolved 'www.inventor-s-hub.xyz'
I have a node.js server running on the port at that domain which works fine if you navigate to it from a browser.
This is the method that I am calling later on in the app which issues a post request:

```
Using System.Net.Http;
public async void PostToServer(string name)
{
      using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
      {
             var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                 { "name", name},
                                 { "id", "1" }
                             };
             var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
             var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.inventor-s-hub.xyz:8000/v8", content);

      }
}
```

I've searched the web but couldn't really find anything relevant, I don't think I am running a proxy on the machine I am issuing the request from.
From the server, I am just sending a 200 status.

Comment: but can you perform a post ? I mean, have you configured /v8 route correctly to receive a post, using postman for example?

Comment: @Forlani yeah I've tested the route with postman and it works fine so the mistake had to be somewhere else, but thanks for the suggestion. What actually worked for me was .EnsureSuccessStatusCode and changing the format of the body of the post from FormUrlEncoded to json which is where I think the problem lied in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample:

```
public static async PostToServer(string name)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                {
                                   { "name", name},
                                   { "id", "1" }
                                };

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://www.inventor-s-hub.xyz:8000/v8"), content );

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return responseBody;
}
```